# ajax in TF in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, html

How can I echo the '**res**' values (returned by a php - mysql) in a text field named "CurrentVal" in HTML?

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'php/myphp.php',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
    var res   =   response[0].result,
            stu   =   response[0].student;
            //console.log(response);
}
});
```

Comment: First you'll need to get the field, if it has an id you can get Element By Id and then set its value to res.

Comment: Thanks Musa... That's exactly what I am after. Can you show that as a code?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:'php/myphp.php',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(response){
    var res   =   response[0].result,
            stu   =   response[0].student;
$('#CurrentVal').val(res);
            //console.log(response);
}
});
```